# Db2 SQL: repeat row using CTE

Tags: common-table-expression, db2-luw, chat-gpt-4

I use following (dummy) code to generate repeated row:
[image: Code]

Results in error:

### 08:33:12  FAILED  [WITH - 0 rows, 0.235 secs]  1) [Code: -343, SQL State: 42908]  The column names are required for the recursive common table expression "myuser.CTE".. SQLCODE=-343, SQLSTATE=42908, DRIVER=4.28.11
2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-343", SQLSTATE "42908" and message tokens "myuser.CTE".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.28.11

Any ideas please;
Thanks

FYKI, the above code sample was created by ChatGPT. Insofar, it must be correct ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried acting on what the message is saying?

"The column names are required for the recursive common table expression"

In other words, try "WITH CTE(row_number) ..."

However, your overall query makes little sense.

If you only want to see 5 table names, then your outer query can use `fetch first 5 rows only` and then you don't need the CTE at all, you only need the query on sysibm.systables with a fetch first clause.

Comment: Thanks, it works insofar, the CTE "WITH" part needs obviously a parameter. 
Unfortunately, it does not function as required; it delivers all names, not only the first 5 as my intent.

Comment: I want the first row of the table 5 times, rather the first 5 rows.

Comment: If you want to get just the 1-st arbitrary sysibm.systables row multiplied by 5 times, then use `... from (select * from sysibm.systables fetch first 1 row only) ...` instead of `... from sysibm.systables ...`.